# Freeing dynamically allocated memory in C while using linked lists

Tags: c, memory-management, struct

I'm trying to familiarize myself with linked lists in C by experimenting with various cases and I have a question. I have written this code and I'm not sure which is the correct way to free the dynamically allocated memory. Just free (S); or do I have to write free (Top); as well and, if yes, does the order of these two commands matter? Also, apart from that, is this code properly written? I would like a thorough explanation if you don't mind, I haven't coded anything for 5 years.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char StackType;

typedef struct StackNodeTag
   {StackType T;
    struct StackNodeTag *Link;
   } StackNode;

typedef struct StackTag
   {struct StackNodeTag *Top;
   } Stack;

typedef Stack *StackPointer;

int main (void)
   {StackPointer S;

    S = malloc (sizeof (Stack));
    S->Top = malloc (sizeof (StackNode));

    S->Top->T = 'c';
    S->Top->Link = NULL;

    free (S->Top);
    free (S);

    return 0;
   }
```

Comment: sounds fine. Order matters because freeing `S` first would render `S->Top` potentially invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is correct. Every malloc() call should have a corresponding free() call, so you'll need both free calls here - S and Top.

In most cases, the order of your calls to free() do not matter. Every malloc() call returns a pointer. So long as you call free with the same pointers that are returned by malloc, you can free data in any order.

However, the order of the free() calls matters in this case, because your only reference to Top is through S. Once you free S, you should not reference any of the data stored in the struct referred to by S.

In many implementations, if you access data in a freed struct directly after freeing it, you'll get lucky and the data will still be there. However, this is bad practice since there is no guarantee that the data will be left as is. For this reason, your call to free(S->Top) must come before free(S).

For example, an equally valid way of freeing this data would be to 1) save the StackNode pointer to a temporary variable, 2) free S, and 3) free Top using the temporary variable. However, the way you have written this is better, as it is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to free everything that was allocated with the `malloc` or similar function, and order does matter.

Since you have a dynamically allocated item *within* another, you must free from the inside out. If you were to free `S` before `S->Top`, you would potentially have a memory leak because you free memory that contained `malloc` data within handling it.

Answer (score 1):

The number of calls to `malloc` should be the same as the number of calls to `free`.

What you have will work properly.  As far as order, you just need to make sure that the memory you want to free is reachable.  For example, in your code if you did `free(S)` first, you wouldn't be able to successfully call `free(S->Top)` since `S` no longer points to valid memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of malloc and free is correct, and is the only order that will work.

The stack pointed to by S must exist before its element Top can be accessed/assigned.  Further, if S is freed before S->Top you will orphan the memory pointed to by S->Top with no way to access or free it (you can't free S->Top if the Stack pointed to by S no longer exists).

I also suggest correcting a few stylistic issues to make your code more legible.

```
// Original
int main (void)
{StackPointer S;
  ..
}
```

This is difficult to read with code on the same line as the opening bracket.  It's not that it can't be understood, just that it's not understandable at a glance.

```
// Easier to read
int main(void)
{
  StackPointer S;
  ..
}

/* Alternate Style, many will say to use
   the above for functions and this for all
   other bracket notation (structs/unions, control flow) */
int main(void) {
  StackPointer S;
  ..
}
```

These are the two commonly used styles.

.

```
typedef Stack *StackPointer;
...
StackPointer S;
```

This is highly unnecessary and requires the reader to go look up what StackPointer is.

```
Stack *S;
```

This requires no typedef, and it is immediately apparent that S is a pointer to a Stack type.

.

Further, as the stack will presumably always exist you can statically create it (if you like).  This will also change how you access it's members

Modified Code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char StackType;

typedef struct StackNodeTag {
    StackType T;
    struct StackNodeTag *Link;
} StackNode;

typedef struct {
    StackNode *Top;
} Stack;

int main (void)
{
    Stack S;

    S.Top = (StackNode *) malloc(sizeof(StackNode));

    S.Top->T = 'c';
    S.Top->Link = NULL;

    free (S.Top);

    return 0;
}
```